# How to check string numeric validator in JTtextField in key pressed event

Tags: java, validation

I am sucessful in validating numeric values for numeric values while the user types the values as

```
if (evt.getKeyChar() >= '0' && evt.getKeyChar() <= '9' || (a == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ) {
    txtPrice.setEditable(true);
    lblPriceErr.setVisible(false);
} else {
   txtPrice.setEditable(false);
   lblPriceErr.setText("* Number only");
   lblPriceErr.setVisible(true);
}
```

How do I make numeric string validator in this same way?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, don't use a `KeyListener` when trying to perform real time validation of text components.

Instead, use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html), that's what they're designed for.  Take a look at [this](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for examples, included a number of "numeric" filter examples.

To validate a `String`, you can simply use [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).  Make sure you wrap each in a `try-catch` and trap a `NumberFormatException`.  This will tell you when the `String` can't be converted to a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an input verifier

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setInputVerifier(new InputVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        String text = ((JTextField) input).getText();
        if (text.matches("\\d+")) // Reads: "Any digit one or more times"
            return true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

This won't stop the user from typing a non-digit, but the text field will not yield focus.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I want to set a numeric string validator. not numeric validator

Comment: @viper What's the difference?